# Как я могу менять значения БД из внешнего файла?

Tags: python, django

Я новичок в django поэтому плохо понимаю разные термины.
Я использую сторонний графический модуль и хочу через него работать со значения в базе данных:
удалять, добавлять и изменять.
Другими словами я хочу запустить файл который не связан с django и html структурой
получить определённое значение.
Например из

```
from models import Artikle
a = Article.objects.get(id = 1)
show_window(a)
```

Мне посоветовали использовать REST API но изо специфического вопроса я не нашел нужного ответа.
Я хочу работать с сайтом не только из браузера но и из моего собственного графического приложения.

Comment: пишешь api (например drf) и из другого приложения просто отправляешь запросы(get,post,update,delete) к api

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin  единственное что я нашел связанное с DRF это `pip install drfdocs` `INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'rest_framework_docs',
)` единственное что я нахожу это лишь туториалы создание дополнительных панелей в браузере. может ли кто не будь дать наглядный пример для изучения?

Comment: Для начала думаю подойдёт https://www.google.com/amp/s/webdevblog.ru/sozdanie-django-api-ispolzuya-django-rest-framework-apiview/amp/ . Если прикручивать что-то более сложное то тогда надо читать оф доки https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Как я понял я могу получить доступ к бд используя `Serializers`? 
Просто меня смущает тот факт что все операций происходят внутри `views.py` 
К которой подключен `from .models import Article` 
Ведь каждый раз когда я подключаю models у меня высвечивается ошибка
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin  Весь туториал основан на отображении и работе в браузере. И у меня никак не получается запустить свой файл `my_code.py`
так что бы он получил доступ к БД. ведь как я говорил при импорте объектов случаются ошибки.

Comment: сейчас приведу небольшой пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть небольшая модель с одним полем.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название категории', max_length = 100, null=True)
```

пишем сериализатор

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name_category')
```

дальше используем `viewset` из `drf`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import CategorySerializer
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

теперь прописываем роуты, можно использовать `DefaultRouter()` но я прописал руками(мне так удобнее)

```
from .views import CategoryViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/post/', CategoryViewSet.as_view({'post':'create'})),
    path('api/get/', CategoryViewSet.as_view({'get':'list','get_queryset':'get_queryset'})),
    path('api/del/<int:pk>',  CategoryViewSet.as_view({'put':'update','get':'retrieve','delete':'destroy'})),
]
```

Теперь у нас есть полностью функционирующие минимальное API и мы можем выполнять все основные задачи API, т. е. Операции Create Read Update Delete (CRUD).

Теперь создаю обычный файл со скриптом
Для того чтобы получить все категории пишим такой небольшой скрипт

```
import requests, json

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get/"
res = requests.get(url)
pars=json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(pars)
```

Для того чтобы добавить новую запись

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/" 

data = {
    'name_category':'test'
}
res = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Теперь для того чтобы удалить какую-нибудь запись

```
import requests

data_description = 10 #id записи которую хотим удалить 
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/del/" + str(data_description) 

response = requests.delete(
    url, 
)
```

для `put` запроса попробуйте написать сами)

Answer (score 0):

Я вроде разобрался но ответ является слегка не точным
и пришлось сверятся с другим туториалом что бы во всем разобратся
Я напишу небольшой туториал того что я сделал для тех кто также туп как и я

1 Вначале нужно установить

```
pip install django
pip install djangorestframework
```

2 после создать проект

```
django-admin startproject myfirst
```

myfirst - это название проекта вы можете заменить его на свое собственное название

3 создать приложение к нему

```
python manage.py startapp articles
```

manage.py - это основной файл к котором можно отдовать команды находится рядом с проэктом

articles - это название приложения вы можите заменить его на свое собственое назвние

4 После в файле `..myfirst\settings.py` найти `INSTALLED_APPS` и добавить

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'articles'
]
```

rest_framework - это подключение к djangorestframework

articles - это название приложения

5 после в `..\articles\models.py` нужно прописать

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name_category = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Название категории', max_length = 100, null=True)
```

Category - это название модуля

name_category - название параметра

verbose_name - отображаемое название параметра

max_length - максимальное количество символов

6 это не обязательно но что бы увидеть изменения сразу в файле `..\articles\admin.py`
нужно добавить

```
from .models import Category
admin.site.register(Category)
```

7 После сделать миграцию модулей

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

8 После нужно создать админ пользователя

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Выбрать имя пользователя, email, пароль и подтверждение пароля
При наборе пароля никакие символы не будут высвечиваться

9 для проверки правильности каждого этапа нужно включать

```
python manage.py runserver
```

и зайти на сайт `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` и войти использовал имя и пароль

10 после создать файл в `article\settings.py` и `article\urls.py`

11 в файле `article\settings.py` написать

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Category
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name_category')
```

12 написать в `articles\views.py` следующее

```
from .models import Category
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import CategorySerializer

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

13 создать url привязку для этого нужно в `myfirst\urls.py` добавить

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('articles.urls')),
]
```

А после в `articles\urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import CategoryViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path('get/', CategoryViewSet.as_view({'get':'list','get_queryset':'get_queryset'})),
    path('post/', CategoryViewSet.as_view({'post':'create'})),
    path('del/<int:pk>',  CategoryViewSet.as_view({'put':'update','get':'retrieve','delete':'destroy'})),
]
```

14 И после создать любой независимый файл и написать

Для получения

```
import requests, json

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get/"
res = requests.get(url)
pars=json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(pars)
```

Для добавления

```
import requests
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/" 

    data = {
        'name_category':'test'
    }
    res = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Для удаления

```
import requests

data_description = 10 #id записи которую хотим удалить 
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/del/" + str(data_description) 

response = requests.delete(
    url, 
)
```

Для обновления

```
import requests

data_description = 10 #id записи которую хотим изменить 
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/del/" + str(data_description) 
data = {
    'name_category':'test'
}
response = requests.put(
    url, 
    data,
)
```